# What can you say about the range space and null space

Tags: matrices

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $T$ a linear operator on $V$. If $T^2$$=$ $0$, what can you say about the relation of the range of $T$ to the null space of $T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$T^2=0\implies \text{Im}\,T\subset\ker T\implies \dim\text{Im}\,T\le\dim\ker T\ldots$$

Comment: why Im T is a subset of Ker T?

Comment: @Mathematics: $$y\in\text{Im}\,T\implies \exists\,x\;\;s.t.\;\;y=Tx\implies Ty=T^2x=0\ldots$$

Comment: oh! Yeah! thank you! @ DonAntonio

Answer (score 3):

We can say:

$$T^2=0\iff \operatorname{Im} T\subset\ker T$$
and the proof is pretty easy.